# Saving images relative to content directory where my site is running in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, file-upload

I want to save images uploaded from a asp mvc page to the content/img/ folder which is relative to where my site is running in IIS. But I don't want to hard code the location on my file system to a Absolute path as this could change easily. This is the code I'm using to save them.

```
  public static string SaveCompanyLogoImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            var newFileName = GetNewCompanyLogoFileName(file.FileName);
            file.FileName = newFileName;
            file.SaveAs(//relative-location-here);
            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(last);
        }
```

Hope this explains my issue!

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Server.MapPath("~/MyImagesFolder")

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Comment: Thanks Oscar! For some reason the Server class is not recognised even though I'm referencing to System.Web in my class libary project.

Comment: Server is a property of the page class. Are you doing this in the page code behind?